# the range of interleukin 2 and 12 that can be used to activate nk-92 cells

Tags: elisa

I am one of the biotech students. I want to know the dynamic ranges of interleukin 2 and 12 that i can use to activate the NK-92 Cells.
    thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have the resources you should ideally titrate your cytokines. You'll find that cytokines from different vendors may exhibit varying stability or availability *in vitro*, but also that you obtain varying levels of activation. Standard NK-92 culture conditions are 100-300 IU/mL IL-2 in RPMI1640 medium, 10% serum and 2mM L-glutamine (or 1X GlutaMAX, life technologies). Activation levels depend on *how much* you want to activate them. Interleukin-12 I'm fairly certain is standard at 10 ng/mL, but should also be titrated.

There's actually a [relevant paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1567576908000829?via%3Dihub) with a fair titration looking at granzyme expression at different concentrations of IL2, IL12 and IL15, and different timepoints. They note that NK92 cells show response at 100, 500 and 1000 IU/mL IL2, and at 10-30ng IL12.